# SQL trigger with parameter

Tags: node.js, sql-server, triggers

I have a nodejs app with SQL Server. I want to be able to update a table for a "specific org" based on an insert and delete action. Let's say I have 2 tables as follows:

- **Project**: projId, orgId, projName
- **Tasks**: taskId, projId, taskName
- **Users**: userId, orgId, userName
- **OrganizationStats**: numberOfProjects, numberOfUsers, numberOfTasks orgId

So let's say I add a new project for an organization where orgId = 1. My insert statement from Nodejs would be:

```
insert into project (projId, orgId, projName) 
values (${'projId'}, ${'orgId'}, 'New Project');
```

I want to write a trigger in SQL Server that adds 1 to the `numberOfProjects` column with `orgId` that's passed in.

```
create trigger updateProjectAfterInsert 
on project 
after insert 
as 
begin 
    update OrganizationStats 
    set numprojects = numberOfProjects + 1 
    where orgId = 'THE_INSERTED_ORGID_VALUE';
end;
```

My problem is I don't know how to pass the `${'orgId'}` to the trigger.

Comment: Use the [Inserted/Deleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) pseudo-tables.

Comment: You also assume that the number of inserted rows is always 1 - a common mistake. But why bother doing this at all? The value can be easily determined by counting the related rows when needed and it will ALWAYS be correct. Did you forget about deletions? Can a project be moved between organizations?

Comment: Personally, I recommend against storing values which can be calculated by an aggregate. If you need such information easily accessible, you're better off making a `VIEW` with the value in there, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want this something like this:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER updateProjectAfterInsert 
  ON Project 
  AFTER INSERT 
  AS 
  BEGIN 
      UPDATE OrganizationStats 
         SET NumProjects = NumProjects + 1 
       WHERE OrgId IN (SELECT OrgId FROM inserted);
  END;
```

Also note, Triggers must always assume multiple rows. It's possible to insert multiple rows, update multiple rows, and delete multiple rows. The "inserted" and "deleted" collections contain the data needed ("inserted" contains the rows being inserted, "deleted" contains the rows being deleted, and on an update "inserted" contains the values after the update, and "deleted" contains the values before the update).

Comment: Note that if 2 projects for the same organisation are inserted at the same time, this will work, but not as the OP expects.

Comment: Hrm, yes, if that's a possible case, then the "+1" should be computed via a correlated subquery most likely.

Comment: orgId is passed in. basically the same logic needs to work for deleted meaning i need to take subtract one from the column.

Comment: `AFTER INSERT` triggers don't occur after a `DELETE` @SeanD .

Comment: Add another AFTER DELETE trigger to handle deletes, @SeanD

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to expand on my comment here:

> Personally, I recommend against storing values which can be calculated by an aggregate. If you need such information easily accessible, you're better off making a VIEW with the value in there, in my opinion.

What I mean by this is that `NumProjects` has "no right" being in the table `OrganizationStats`, instead it should be calculated at the time the information is needed. You can't use an aggregate function in a computed column's definition without a scalar function, and those can be quite slow. Instead I recommend creating a `VIEW` (or if you prefer table value function) to give you the information from the table:

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_OrganisationStats AS

    SELECT {Columns from OrganizationStats},
           P.Projects AS NumProjects
    FROM dbo.OrganizationStats OS
         CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Projects
                      FROM dbo.Projects P
                      WHERE P.OrgID = OS.OrgID) P;
```

I use a `CROSS APPLY` with a subquery, as then you don't need a huge `GROUP BY` at the end.

Comment: So given the above do I need to create 2 more views to calculate the COUNT for numberOfUsers and numberOfTasks as well or can the other two columns get calculated within the same view?

Comment: You would add the to the same view.

Comment: so given the table structure in the original question, I am not sure they'd all get into one view query.. @Lamu Can you please help with a sample code?

Comment: *"Can you please help with a sample code?"* There's one in my question, @SeanD . I don't know your design, or details of requirements that aren't covered in the question, but you can certainly have multiple aggregate functions in a single `VIEW`. If you don't know how to implement the above, you're  better off asking a new question, as you end up invalidating both answers here if you change this question.